# Как прикрепить картинку к товару при создании через WP-CLI?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Дайте, пожалуйста, пример команды, позволяющей при создании товара через CLI добавить к нему картинку.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Что такое CLI??

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов Command Line Interface, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLI

Answer (score 1):

Давайте изучим файл [`includes/cli/class-wc-cli-product.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/cli/class-wc-cli-product.php).

В методе `create` ожидается информация о картинках под ключом `images`.

Вот кусок кода ответственный за это:

```
if ( isset( $data['images'] ) ) {
    $this->save_product_images( $id, $data['images'] );
}
```

Если изучить метод `save_product_images`, становится ясно, что для каждой картинки распознаются следующие ключи: `id`, `position` и `src`, где `src` — это URL-адрес к нашей картинке, а `id` — это на самом деле `attachment_id`.

Как я понял, если указать `id`, будет загружена картинка из галерии с указанным id. Если указан `src`, картинка будет получена по указанному url.

Вот статья о поддержке WP CLI в :
[Sneak Peek: WP CLI Support in WooCommerce 2.5](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/sneak-peek-wp-cli-support-in-woocommerce/)

Если я правильно понял способ парсинга, то загрузка картинки должна происходить как-то так:

```
wp wc product create --images.0.src="http://placehold.it/100x100.png?text=1"
```

`images.0.src` будет развернуто в следующую конструкцию:

```
array(
    'images' => array(
        0 => array(
            'src' => 'http://placehold.it/100x100.png?text=1'
        )
    )
)
```

Я рекомендую вам самостоятельно ознакомиться с файлом [`includes/cli/class-wc-cli-product.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/cli/class-wc-cli-product.php), поскольку с WP CLI я не работал и проверить эту команду смогу только вечером.

---

### Update

Проверил этот вариант команды. Все создается, как и задумано.

Уточнение по картинкам:

```
Картинки передаются массивом, где каждый элемент может быть задан по его индексу:

  * images
  * images.size
  * images.0.id
  * images.0.created_at
  * images.0.updated_at
  * images.0.src
  * images.0.title
  * images.0.alt
  * images.0.position
```

Выполнение команды:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `cmder` - это какая-то сторонняя консоль? Порадовал shell prompt в виде лямбды )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, это сторонняя консоль для винды. [http://cmder.net/](http://cmder.net/). Постоянно ей пользуюсь